# Ocean modifier and foam data export?

Tags: modifiers, export

It is there any way to export the foam data generated from ocean modifier to use it in other render engine, like LuxRender? The manual says that the foam data is stored as vertex color data, but there isn't a way to access the vertexColor data. I know that can be accessed from Cycles from attribute's node. LuxRender supports vertex color and I tried to bake the texture to *vertexColor* and an image but only get a plain black texture.

Comment: foam could be generated as image sequence in blender black and white images you could set resolution for textures as well,but I dont know if image sequence could be used in LUX as texture

Comment: Yes it supports, but even i just gonna render a still, how do i save it as image, i baked as "Texture" bake and nothing.

Comment: probably you doing something wrong during baking it http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Simulate/Ocean works for me this tut is really good about ocean http://youtu.be/11F1NRpqrzY

Answer (score 6):

Finish settings for ocean such as wind, choppiness, etc.

Set resolution in ocean modifier. For example, 16 will result in a baked image 256x256 pixels. 64 is the largest, final baked image is 4096x4096.

Check the boxes for generate normals and Foam,

Set cache path anywhere you want (should be an empty folder) and bake.

After a while you get images like this one in your cache folder:

[image: baked foam]