# How to export your Ocean Modifier Mesh and Animation to Unity? | Blender v2.80.72

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, unity, ocean-simulation

/*Edited: For Blender 2.7 Users I found a detailed [articel](https://sketchfab.com/blogs/community/tutorial-creating-an-animated-ocean-scene-in-blender) with pictures. */

I want to build an VR-Scene in Unity with a little Island and and ocean around.
[image: Example Picture of my current status]

For the ocean I am quite happy with the ocean modifier and made already an looping animation with the water.

[animation Gif](https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipNkczmrUQcPoMlw9iPXgdmutbRh87CZVI3Z07Gt)

But I simply cannot find a solution to export the mesh + animations to Unity. I keyframed the time and scale and found the problem, that these can't update when I apply the modifier. To my understanding blender needs to apply the modifier when exporting, so I can even get the shape of Ocean.

[[image: Picture of my modifier settings[2]]

I tried and failed with [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/how-to-apply-the-ocean-modifier-to-get-an-animated-object/30311#30311) explanation.

Could somebody please give me an more beginner friendly explanation?

Here is my blendfile:
[google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iWU0lf2mK88i9M8Yaz_gwtAf82HKbYFn/view)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/ocean-modifier-and-foam-data-export https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72279/export-ocean-modifier-animation-to-game-engine https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53464/trying-to-export-ocean-modifier-animation-as-collada-file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KFXwSZOEZkUK1K4hLUY0APrCdHQQexrJ

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yeah, none of them solve my question, where the third one doesn't even really has an answer.

Comment: @FFeller okay! Seems like you applied the modifiers and baked the Animation to the frames! That's exactly what I want. So how did you do it?

Comment: First you have to apply the scale with ctrl+a on the ocean (this will mess up the scale, but you can adjust it after the procedure). Then select the ocean and export it to mdd. Then apply the modifiers. After all, just select the ocean again and import the mdd. Then the keyframes will appear, you dont have to use any other modifier. May be you will have two extra frames before the first and after the last frame, which are a little dislocated, but you can easily delete them.

Comment: @FFeller for future readers I want to mention, that you have to enable under  edit -> preference -> add ons ->  Import-Export: NewTek MDD format to even see the option when clicking export.

Comment: @FFeller furthermore I just get an error when I try to export. Am I doing something wrong or is it just the 2.8 beta?

Comment: [Picture of the Error](https://imgur.com/eTHL7T0)

Answer (score 0):

I used the official Blender 2.8 release and it works fine.

What to do:

1. Select your 'Ocean Object' and press ctrl + a to apply the scale.
2. With your object selected click file -> export -> Lightwave Point Cache (.mdd)
3. Save the mdd file.
4. Apply your ocean modifier
5. With the object selected click import and import your mdd file again.

The whole process takes only seconds now.

Comment: You need to have the NewTek MDD format addon enabled to this this option in the export menu.